# How to create a for loop that pulls data from html_nodes and populates table

Tags: r

I have a series of publication identifiers from the RePEc database. I need to get the reference list from the database, which I can do like this:

```
identifier <- "RePEc:imf:imfwpa:01/191"
url_base <- "http://citec.repec.org/api/amf/"
url <- paste0(url_base, identifier)
get_data <- read_html(url)
references <- html_nodes(get_data,'references') %>% html_nodes("text")
```

I get an output that looks like this:

```
print(references)
{xml_nodeset (6)}
[1] <text ref="RePEc:rio:texdis:400"></text>
[2] <text ref="RePEc:fip:fednrp:9608"></text>
[3] <text ref="RePEc:nbr:nberwo:1172"></text>
[4] <text ref="RePEc:bla:ecnote:v:28:y:1999:i:3:p:335-355"></text>
[5] <text ref="RePEc:imf:imfwpa:00/69"></text>
[6] <text ref="RePEc:eee:jbfina:v:24:y:2000:i:1-2:p:203-227"></text>
```

I only want the individual identifiers. In other words, I just want this:

```
[1] "RePEc:rio:texdis:400"                         
[2] "RePEc:fip:fednrp:9608"                       
[3] "RePEc:nbr:nberwo:1172"                        
[4] "RePEc:bla:ecnote:v:28:y:1999:i:3:p:335-355"  
[5] "RePEc:imf:imfwpa:00/69"                       
[6] "RePEc:eee:jbfina:v:24:y:2000:i:1-2:p:203-227"
```

I tried using `html_text(references)` but it just gave me a series of empty cells..

Once I have this data, I want to create a dataframe with each of these values next to the original identifier. In other words, I need something like this:

```
identifier <- c("RePEc:imf:imfwpa:01/191", "RePEc:imf:imfwpa:01/191", "RePEc:imf:imfwpa:01/191", "RePEc:imf:imfwpa:01/191", "RePEc:imf:imfwpa:01/191", "RePEc:imf:imfwpa:01/191")
references <- c("RePEc:rio:texdis:400", "RePEc:fip:fednrp:9608", "RePEc:nbr:nberwo:1172", "RePEc:bla:ecnote:v:28:y:1999:i:3:p:335-355", "RePEc:imf:imfwpa:00/69", "RePEc:eee:jbfina:v:24:y:2000:i:1-2:p:203-227")
df <- data.frame(identifier, references)
```

I need to do this with about 180,000 different documents. I think I can write a for loop myself once I know how to do it once but if anyone has a smart way to do this, I would be very grateful for your advice. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Add `%>% html_attr("ref")` after `html_nodes("text")` and you should get the desired text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Document is an XML. I think using `xml2` more appropriate.

```
library(xml2)

identifier <- "RePEc:imf:imfwpa:01/191"
url_base <- "http://citec.repec.org/api/amf/"
url <- paste0(url_base, identifier)

references <- read_xml(url) %>%
  xml_find_all("//d1:references/d1:text") %>%
  xml_attr("ref")
```

**Output**

```
# [1] "RePEc:rio:texdis:400"                        
# [2] "RePEc:fip:fednrp:9608"                       
# [3] "RePEc:nbr:nberwo:1172"                       
# [4] "RePEc:bla:ecnote:v:28:y:1999:i:3:p:335-355"  
# [5] "RePEc:imf:imfwpa:00/69"                      
# [6] "RePEc:eee:jbfina:v:24:y:2000:i:1-2:p:203-227"
```

You need to install `xml2` package to make it works

```
install.packages("xml2")
```

---

OR, as mentioned by **Ben**, with `rvest`, just add `html_attr("ref")` into your script

```
get_data <- read_html(url)
references <- html_nodes(get_data,'references') %>% 
  html_nodes("text") %>% 
  html_attr("ref")
```

---

For multiple identifier, you can wrap the script in function, then call it using `lapply` or `sapply`.

```
# function
get_reference <- function(identifier) {
  url_base <- "http://citec.repec.org/api/amf/"
  url <- paste0(url_base, identifier)
  references <- read_xml(url) %>%
    xml_find_all("//d1:references/d1:text") %>%
    xml_attr("ref")
  df <- data.frame(identifier = identifier, references = references, stringsAsFactors = F)
}

# list of identifier as input
identifier <- c("RePEc:imf:imfwpa:01/191","RePEc:imf:imfwpa:02/191")

# scrape and combine
df <- lapply(identifier, get_reference) %>% do.call(rbind, .)
```

**Output**

```
#                 identifier                                   references
# 1  RePEc:imf:imfwpa:01/191                         RePEc:rio:texdis:400
# 2  RePEc:imf:imfwpa:01/191                        RePEc:fip:fednrp:9608
# 3  RePEc:imf:imfwpa:01/191                        RePEc:nbr:nberwo:1172
# 4  RePEc:imf:imfwpa:01/191   RePEc:bla:ecnote:v:28:y:1999:i:3:p:335-355
# 5  RePEc:imf:imfwpa:01/191                       RePEc:imf:imfwpa:00/69
# 6  RePEc:imf:imfwpa:01/191 RePEc:eee:jbfina:v:24:y:2000:i:1-2:p:203-227
# 7  RePEc:imf:imfwpa:02/191                       RePEc:wck:wckewp:34/99
# 8  RePEc:imf:imfwpa:02/191                        RePEc:nbr:nberwo:7018
# 9  RePEc:imf:imfwpa:02/191                     RePEc:wop:wispod:1132-97
# 10 RePEc:imf:imfwpa:02/191    RePEc:aea:aecrev:v:88:y:1998:i:3:p:478-94
# 11 RePEc:imf:imfwpa:02/191                         RePEc:mie:wpaper:341
# 12 RePEc:imf:imfwpa:02/191    RePEc:eee:inecon:v:4:y:1974:i:2:p:177-185
# 13 RePEc:imf:imfwpa:02/191                      RePEc:imf:imfwpa:97/116
# 14 RePEc:imf:imfwpa:02/191                        RePEc:nbr:nberwo:7539
# 15 RePEc:imf:imfwpa:02/191   RePEc:aea:aecrev:v:90:y:2000:i:2:p:161-167
# 16 RePEc:imf:imfwpa:02/191     RePEc:eee:inecon:v:50:y:2000:i:1:p:51-71
# 17 RePEc:imf:imfwpa:02/191                        RePEc:nbr:nberwo:5427
# 18 RePEc:imf:imfwpa:02/191                        RePEc:eee:ecochp:5-58
# 19 RePEc:imf:imfwpa:02/191                        RePEc:nbr:nberwo:6591
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Do you know how I can turn this output into a dataframe (i.e. the second part of my question)?